# Primarily Opinion Based - Wording

Tags: feature-request, rules

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

I propose that the words "or specific expertise" be removed.
after several encounters with other members discussing the situation with "opinion-based" answer -type questions, I believe the conclusion (from other members) is that:

- NO question should promote opinions.

therefore:

- "or specific expertise" should be removed
- any or all types of questions related to sciences or fields that have not yet been
  COMPLETELY discovered and defined should be banned.
- any or all types of questions that involve the words "Pros/Cons" should be banned. (I would see this as being "Too Broad" like someone else had stated to me, but it seems many people construe this as being "opinion-based" as well)

These new rules are much more CLEAR and DEFINED, especially for newbies.
There will be no room for arguments.
StackOverflow can be exactly the way the other members say it should be, as of now.

---

There exists questions that do not have specific definitive answers. Trying to ask a question about those topics always causes criticism on the post's wording and/or some other topic that does not have to do with actual subject of the question.

I.E.
 Posting a question: within which you state you want responses from VERY Experienced experts in the industry/field because the question pertains to a topic that does not exactly have a definitive answer. 
I wanted to know what the experts thinks, since questions like this do not have hard concrete answers, the only way to get a close enough "definitive" answer (and make progress towards a "definitive" answer) would probably be to "ask an expert for his 'opinion'" on the matter.
However, this is seen as asking for opinions because:

- I am asking for what an expert "thinks" or "feels"
- There is no definitive answer to the question

I propose we remove these sources of heartache, since the end results are the same (no real good discussion or answers, just closing out the thread).

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning behind removing "specific expertise."  Specific expertise is exactly what askers should expect from answers.

Comment: Also, note that closing questions will never be an unambiguous process.  If it could be made unambiguous, there would be no need for a close voting system.

Comment: what do you mean by unambiguous closing?

Comment: I mean that closing is always a judgement call.  Granted, there are clear-cut cases, but there's still a lot of gray area.  That's why we require 5 community members to close a question, not just one.

Comment: oh right. yea i dont have a problem with that at all

Comment: Updated a bit in response to your "specific expertise" inquiry

Comment: In response to your update, asking for "specific expertise" as the answer to a broad, vaguely worded question doesn't make the question itself any better, any more than adding "as a programmer" to the title does (as in "what are the best pickles to eat as a programmer?").

Comment: in my opinion, although opinions dont matter here, i think that makes it quite specific and it is that exact specificity that I am trying to reach from an expert, since that is probably as good as I can get at the moment without additional constraints.

I think my question is as specific as my situation calls for as I am still in a R&D type phase. If this is true, then what avenue do i have for asking this type of question? I want to ask an expert what he feels about a situation because I would only trust feedback from an expert in the field.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Incidentally, from one programmer to another, what *are* the best pickles to eat?

Comment: @Jsh562 The site is designed to encourage/allow questions that are written and worded in such a way as to encourage high quality answers and to prohibit or discourage low quality answers.  Because of this, people without a sufficient level of expertise wouldn't be *able* to adequately answer any given question.  You're trying to ask a poorly worded, vague, broad, open ended, subjective question, and then prohibit non-experts only by saying so, rather than by asking for something that a non-expert would be unable to provide (facts/expertise) rather than something anyone can provide (opinions).

Comment: my question generalizes for the site's audience. the information i am seeking is inherently something that an expert would be able to provide through experience and a non-expert would be able to give opinions on through whatever. due to this fact, the responses themselves would inherently show the level of expertise of the respondees. there is no need to filter out respondees beforehand by stating in BOLD HEADLINES that I ONLY WANT EXPERTS IN THE FIELD, if the filter will automatically happen through quality of responses.

Comment: The question is broad because I want the expert to know what I am talking about. and the non-experts to think they know what i am talking about. Responses from experts are what I am seeking, but responses from non-experts could also be valuable too (rare finds, missing info, new directionality) so I do not mind having all sorts of people post their responses, as long as I have some way to filter out quality of responses....

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how it works.  We don't screen answers for possible questions; we screen questions for possible answers, and some questions, by their very nature, are magnets for spam and bad answers, which is why we don't allow them.  A person who has enough knowledge of the subject matter can surely ask a well-focused, properly-researched question.  The person who doesn't (or can't) do this probably won't understand the answers anyway.

Comment: if i had "enough" knowledge, i probably would never have to post a question here. no? The person who doesn't understand high-quality answers given to them can do additional research from that point on. no?

Comment: You need sufficient *background knowledge.*  The person that has this can focus their question to their specific challenge, problem or issue.  The person that does not have this cannot focus their question, and cannot understand the answers they are given.

Comment: so only ask questions that you would fully understand the answers to?

Comment: No.  But it's pointless to ask "why is the sky blue" if you don't have the necessary background in concepts like diffraction to properly understand the answer.  [See here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMFPe-DwULM) for an illustration of what I mean.

Comment: i think we are straying from the original topic, but i think there still is a point to asking why it is blue if you dont understand physics. u get led onto a path that will help, while helping others.
And what I am saying is that its usually not the lack of background knowledge that made me not put details into the question, usually its because I want to consider all aspects from a slightly higher viewpoint, there are no facts yet due to planning/research stage, or (more often than not) the reader doesnt know what details I am already referring to within the question (reader is not an expert).

Comment: When I do not have a specific test bed in mind yet, but I still am concerned about the different aspects or properties of the affected system, I still would want to ask a slightly broad question to experts in the field to make sure I get things taken care of before they become a big issue later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel this may be an unpopular answer but I actually *sort of* agree with the spirit of this proposed change, although I do not agree with most of the points and stated reasons, I do not agree with the removal of "specific expertise", and I cannot think of any changes that I *would* agree with.

I also do not think it is a major issue. It always stings a little to get used to a new place and I feel that this proposal is primarily driven by a need to off-load the "blame" for the misunderstanding to something external source (semantics of wording in close reason vs. "oops, I was mistaken").

I do feel that the OP has misinterpreted the reasons, and I also feel that the misinterpretation is rather unique to him (and maybe a few others) as, as far as I know, we don't actually see a lot of complaints about this particular point.

That said, I did actually think, when reading [the OP's previous related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228683/primarily-opinion-based-and-not-based-on-specific-expertise-database-normaliza), that I could see where his misunderstanding came from, and identified those particular words in the close reason as the source. I thought this immediately when I read the previous question, before this proposal was made.

The primary "issue" identified by this proposal is this (emphasis mine):

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on **opinions, rather than** facts, references, or **specific expertise**.

It's a very subtle wording issue, but if taken very literally, this is what happens in the interpretation:

- *"... tend to be based almost entirely on opinion"* => Opinion-based is bad.
- *"... rather than ..."* => A contrasting list of acceptable things will follow.
- *"... specific expertise."* => Ah, "specific expertise" trumps other opinion-based.

This happens if the statement is read in a "default deny -> allow by exception" sort of way. Subtle, but a misread could lead to the idea that answers based on "specific expertise" are always acceptable. Note also that "specific expertise" is not 100% analogous to "facts" and "references" (which *cannot* be opinion-based), but the description lumps the three together.

Really, though, it is about the question itself. The question that spawned this discussion is almost more "too broad" than "opinion based", simply because there's not enough information for even the most specific of expertise to yield an applicable, well-formed answer.

Again, I feel this misunderstanding is somewhat unique to the OP (we don't actually have a lot of people who misunderstand that), and I'm not pushing for a change (I honestly don't think it's necessary, and it would be tricky to word it correctly anyways), but I do want to point out that I at least see where this might be stemming from.

Comment: Exactly one of my initial thoughts.
Thank you for being open minded and understanding of my situation.
If i had 15rep... =D

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here. That " 'specific expertise' answers are always acceptable" is a legitimate misread? Every interpretation is a legitimate misread.

Comment: @djechlin The point I am trying to make is that I understand *how* the OP misinterpreted the reason, even though I disagree with the proposal; and I wanted to illustrate that to others (since interpretation can be a tricky thing, sometimes it's hard to conceive of how a different person possibly could have interpreted something the way they did - then endless conflicts ensue). I think the wording of the reason is fine as is. I was trying to show that I disagreed but also understood. I realize my post is vague and could be better organized.

Comment: @djechlin Also I did pretty clearly state that I felt this particular misinterpretation was relatively rare.

Comment: This does not happen to me on only "rare" occasions,
and is one of the reasons why I posted my questions onto Meta in this fashion. I was hoping to get a DIFFERENT response this time instead of the usual, "You are wrong, its so obvious to us all"-type responses, and so far I got Jason C to be able to look/think outside the box, which I am very grateful for. I put my "proposals" and issues with the community's reactions here in this fashion to try to make an impact on the community, which otherwise would have gone largely unnoticed (from past experience).

Answer (score 4):

Virtually every single possible question is going to generate *some* degree of opinion.  If your suggestion were made, then just about every single question on the site would be inappropriate; the site might as well just shut down.

The goal, as is stated, is to remove questions that are *primarily* opinion based; in which the opinion stated in an answer is more important than or would otherwise overwhelm any facts, evidence, or expertise within it.

Your edit makes it sound like you want questions that are *primiarly* opinion based to be allowed.  You want to ask questions where you are getting *advise*, where you are interested not in facts or evidence, but in just the opinion of the asker.  These are question that we *do not want here*.  There is a *lot* of space between, "entirely objective, has no subjectively" and "entirely subjective, contains no evidence".  The design of the site is to draw a line somewhere in the middle.  A degree of subjectivity/opinions is important, but it's important that it not overwhelm objective fact and evidence within an answer.  You're seeing this as a purely binary decision; either we allow opinions or we don't.  The issue is more analog.  It's a question of *how much* subjectivity we allow, not *if* we allow it.

> any or all types of questions that involve the words "Pros/Cons" should be banned

As I mentioned in [my answer to your previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228686/186381); this is, in most instances, going to make a question "too broad", rather than "primarily opinion based", even though there is actually a large amount of subjectivity here.

Comment: oh yea. sorry thats true

Answer (score 2):

StackExchange has taken a strong stance against this, which is covered in this post: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

There's a lot of good stuff called "expertise" that can be accurately and consistently recognized by others, but nobody has bothered to put in a book or article. If I solve a hard problem in programming or technology, do I really need to put it in a book or on Wikipedia before I can share it with fellow programmers? That would make me an expert, and the knowledge would originate with me. And I might choose to publish it on StackExchange, where it might actually *become* the canonical reference on the topic.

That's why this stuff is allowed. Because it's really good and vital, really often.

> any or all types of questions related to sciences or fields that have not yet been COMPLETELY discovered and defined should be banned.

This is really extreme and ridiculous. One, I don't know whether a programming question has a solution when I ask it all of the time. If I did, I would find the solution and do it. Two, if someone sees my post and *figures out* how to do it - you want to ban them from sharing it with me because it hasn't been solved already, or they lack a reference for something they just figured out right there? We're not Wikipedia, nor should we be.

Comment: I would hope so as well, as i see R&D as EXTREMELY vital.