# Is it just me who sees it, or is the new review system really effective?

Tags: discussion, review

I tried (for the first time) the shining new review page a few days ago, as I understood that there is a new, smarter way to do it.

It seems that the big pile of "Low quality posts" goes down much faster than before. I remember seeing it at about 32k posts yesterday morning and it counts now 29.4k posts.

Is it true that the trend changed significantly after the introduction of the new review system? If yes, that's a bit congrats to you, guys!

**Update**

Time has answered my question. The image below (taken on Sept 9, 2012) is a good illustration of the result:

> [image]

Comment: I haven't been keeping track of the Low Quality numbers, but the suggested edit queue used to be near full most of the time, and now it's consistently near zero. So, the bite-size approach seems to be effective at getting things processed. Unfortunately, speed doesn't [fix the quality issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137784/131713).

Comment: On the other hand, the close votes queue keeps growing, I'd suspect that quite a few of the low quality posts are handled by voting to close.

Comment: @Monolo It seems you got it! That's very true!

Comment: Monolo, that may be a good thing! There is a high probability for low quality posts to be close-worthy.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting close votes...it's important to gauge the success of a new tool. It's not like this is a rant/impossible to answer.

Comment: @EmilVikström Absolutely! I just wanted to point out that the close votes queue is _not_ shrinking, on the contrary: it is growing. I am all for closing (and deleting) stuff that isn't up to snuff, and my threshold is pretty low, btw.

Comment: I'm quite sure there are more people reviewing suggested edit, but I'm quite sure that some of them don't know what a good edit is and end up playing clicking button game instead of seriously reviewing the posts.

Comment: I have to say it's certainly an effective system for the smaller sites; UX burned our backlog out in a couple days.

Comment: I am a bit dissapointed by the closure - I was expecting a simple answer, backed by some numbers (the backlog burn rate before and after the introduction of the new system) that sounds like a reasonable and interesting question

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145657/nom-nom-nom-no-more-low-quality-posts-any-stats-on-how-they-sorted-out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For both low quality answers, and also suggested edits, it's clear that they are being process much quicker since the introduction of the new system.  The question of *why* still remains to be answered.  Here are some theories (some mine, some others).

- The new queue is more user friendly.  Since people like it, they use it more.
- We now have a fancy (and reasonably visible) leaderboard for actions performed each queue (day/total).  People want to get their names higher up on that board.
- Showing one problem post at a time, rather than showing a list of many, is preferable.  (With more theories as to why, whether it's lack of intimidation, forcing people to make a decision, or what.)
- The feature is just new.  People are experimenting; new stuff is cool; they'll get bored soon enough and it'll go back to what it was.
- Because of all of the posts about the new features, and relevant discussions, more people are finding the review tool that just didn't know it existed before (or didn't know where it was, didn't know they could use it, didn't know how to use it, etc).
- The SO team has been bribing people (with cookies) to do work in the new queues.

Of course in practice it's probably at least a little bit of all of these, it's more a question of how much of each rather than which one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I saw the Low Quality queue at around 80k when the new review system was release so it may indeed be an effective system. The real question though is if the queue is emptied by adding quality (actually reading posts and editing them if they can be improved) or if people are just blindly pressing the same button over and over? I think this will need to be evaluated by the SE staff some time soon.

Comment: They're [already on it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143380/131713), actually.