# Why is this a "Low quality post"?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review-beta: Obviously good answer in low-quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality)

I like the new reviewing system ([in beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139536/168269)). But today a "low quality post" puzzled me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11606577/861716.

[image]

---

Why is this deemed "low quality"? It's got 7 upvotes, it's well-written and it's not evidently short (ugh). [The heuristics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer) don't seem to give any reason for it to stand out.

In general I think that the algorithm does a very good job, but this time it made me scratch my head.

Comment: Wait a min... there is a post regarding this... Here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality

Comment: Ah good one! Duplicate then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, `this doesn't perfectly answer your question` sentence triggered false alert.

This should be a flip side of the script being capable to recognize garbage answers like

> I know *this doesn't answer the question* but I am curious about how you did <something irrelevant>

*This doesn't perfectly answer your question* but I believe the best course of action in cases like this is to click <kbd>Looks Good</kbd> and move on.

Comment: The description says that it is flagged because of its **length** and content - which is not the case here, since the post is very long. It is more likely a test to see whether the reviewer is doing the job properly.

Comment: Well, content could be a reason if the algorithm is triggered by the sentence gnat points out. But I'm not sure if it is. I think the worst answers are those given by people who are not aware of it not being an answer. Anyway, I voted "looks good" and probably passed the test :).

Comment: @nhahtdh "and" in description wording is likely misleading; I wouldn't be surprised if it means to say **"and/or"** - resolving in our case to "content" part. Thing is, the only reasonable underlying heuristics that could be there should react to "content" part I mentioned

Comment: @gnat: I just check the LQ queue to make sure. You are probably right. I think it doesn't bother whether it is just length, just content or both and slap the same message there.