# "Severe quality issues" screen on already deleted message

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts, review-audits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review-beta: Obviously good answer in low-quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality)

Upon reviewing some messages, I received the "This post has severe quality issues" teaching screen. I guess I've let something slip, I'm perfectly fine with it, but I'm not sure I'm about to learn what:

> [image: Severe quality issues bug]

I guess it's some kind of timing issue? Like the original answer has been deleted at the exact moment the page was displayed to me?

Comment: More than likely it's timing

Comment: @ChrisF I don't know, this looks like it's on purpose. Something like "hey, see what others have deleted, and learn from it". The description even says "don't worry, we've already handled this..."

Comment: @YannisRizos - Now I look at the screen shot properly I see what you mean.

Comment: @YannisRizos Which wouldn't be a bad thing if the deleted message was visible

Comment: @KooKiz Yes, that would have been my next comment, that the deleted answer should be deleted, but you should still see it there. I was responding to if it was bad timing or not, it seems like a different bug all together.

Comment: I don't see how it's a duplicate. I know there's test answers to verify whether the reviewer isn't just mechanically clicking "close" or "looking good". The point here is that this time there was no answer at all.