# Why was this answer from Jon Skeet "automatically flagged as low-quality"?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts, review-audits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review-beta: Obviously good answer in low-quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality)

Why was this answer from Jon Skeet "automatically flagged as low-quality"?

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/950051

[image]

Comment: I _knew_ that Skeet guy was overrated.

Comment: Be careful - if you recommend deletion on that one then the universe will implode and become a black hole. Having said that, you should edit it - the answer is clearly substandard because he hasn't put the opening brace of the `for` loop on a new line, a classic n00b mistake.

Comment: +1 for my first laugh of the day :-D