# Clicking close button to preview reasons to close an item

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This may be bad practice (thus my reason for asking) but I often click the "close" button just to preview the reasons people might want to close.

The only reason I bring this up is that a seemingly good answer with a number of upvotes that was also marked as accepted came up in my "close" queue. I clicked "close" with no intention of closing the task. I just wanted to see why on earth it should be in my list. I was then admonished by the website, telling me that I need to be careful, etc. Being the paranoid sort, I am assuming I'm under some kind of probation now regarding my reviews of close votes and other review items. Perhaps this is a good measure and necessary to help prevent robo-closers who are trying to get a badge or something. But I was acting in good faith.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not aware of any such probation or ban system being active in the queues at this time. The warning is more likely given for questions that have been given a lot of `do not close` votes already.

Comment: Freak out less.  If you're truly acting in good faith, and have a good history of reviews, you won't have any serious problems.  Currently these posts (unless there has been a recent change) don't *do* anything; the results are merely recorded for the SE team's benefit.  Presumably at some indeterminate point in the future they'll actually *do* something.

Comment: How are you still alive? The system must not be working then....strange.

Comment: @Servy I had to re-read my question to find where I was freaking out. I did use the phrase "why on earth", which I guess could be considered harsh language to sensitive folks. I'll try to keep it civil. ☺

Comment: @MrBoJangles Actually I was referring to, "Being the paranoid sort, I am assuming I'm under some kind of probation".  I was saying, "don't worry so much; everything will be okay".

Comment: I'm only paranoid because everyone's out to get me. It's a known issue, suffice it to say.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this issue with review audits still occur? (I vaguely recall that it got fixed at some point...)

Answer (score 1):

Major edit: As per Servy's comment, the checks system shouldn't call you out until you actually click the final "close" button. A decent proposal with which I agree.

Comment: I disagree.  I think that, given this is brand new functionality, it's still subject to improvement.  It shouldn't scold you until you confirm a close reason, rather than just bringing up the close menu.

Comment: That sounds sensible. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I *wonder* if this could possibly be associated with the good answers that are thrown in with the bad (officially termed '[gotchas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143380/176080)') to check that people aren't robot-reviewing?  If the prompt is perhaps generated when you click close on one of those?

If that is the case then it's a good new feature, however MrBoJangles is right that the warning should only be triggered if you actually attempt to cast a close vote rather than juts looking at the dialogue.  Although then I suppose the close vote would have to be intercepted before the genuinely good question had close votes piled on to it.

I'd be really very surprised if there was any logging of who is triggering those messages and even if there was I'm sure that it wouldn't count against you for the first time.