# Low quality posts though Accepted answers

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review-beta: Obviously good answer in low-quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality)

Recently I reviewed one [low quality post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1137155) which has  few upvotes and also it is accepted answer. I believe it should not be flagged as low quality posts. I have gone through [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer) which describes how bad answers are being detected.

Sometimes some one liner answers works magically and also accepted (not able to find such case but may be). I believe those answers should be excluded from low quality posts.

Please suggest what should be done, excluded or not?

Comment: I know this is `states-bydesign`. :)

Comment: @hims056 than I should delete question than ?

Comment: Nah. I also know this is duplicate. Just wait to search.

Comment: Related: [Review-beta: Obviously good answer in low-quality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142998/187824)

Comment: @hims056 In my case I am asking for accepted answers. Not exactly but sort of.

Answer (score 5):

I've said this somewhere before, but it's always better to have false positives than to miss out on truly low-quality posts. The problem is, there *are* accepted answers which are low-quality and deserve to be deleted. Adding these exclusions would only make it that much easier for users to slip through the cracks.

As for your specific example, that was only a review audit meant to make sure you're paying attention.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot exclude one-line answers from the low quality review queue because the system cannot determine the quality of the answer, only the length. It takes a human to determine the quality.

This applies even if the answer is accepted, or the author has a high rep (I have seen bad one line answers from high rep users - some are current, some from the days when they were a low rep user).

Comment: @Jennis There is no requirement to accept any particular answer. Some of the other guys round here may have some more valuable input than me, just wait and see if they drop by.