# Do questions and answeres in beta sites go into the eyes of quality reviewers?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts, beta-sites

I am just curious to know if beta sites are by default get the attention of reviewers? Or rather the reviewing mechanism is in place for beta site questions and answers?

There seems to be some cases where answerers who just provide one liners also some who don't seem to ask a quality question in betas.

I have seen:

[Review-beta: Obviously good answer in low-quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality)

Comment: The question you reference, on a brute force prime factorization code analysis, has answers to do not get to the needed result. The net problem with all the answers is that they do not get to the result that any such brute force code to do prime factorization, while it may represent a "computational method" that would get to a solution ... it will NOT do so in any reasonable time and power consumption. This isn't a "code" problem, it is "how do I develop a better algorithm or a "near algorithm" (one that often produces an answer more quickly, but may not.  See research on prime factorization..

Comment: @ErstwhileIII I guess I was barking at the wrong tree... What I want to know if beta questions and answers go under review like any other SE site out there on regular basis.

Answer (score 3):

The questions and answers on beta sites, like those on all Stack network sites, are reviewable by qualified users on those sites. At the beginning of a beta, there are precious few users of any stripe, let alone users with sufficient reputation to review, and so there won't be as much reviewing or downvoting as on a normal site. Initially, it's all up to the pro-tem moderators. A healthy beta will quickly reach the point where there are as many reviewers as needed, however.