# Make edits always count as review

Tags: feature-request, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The current review system encourages faux reviews: some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-faux-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything)

Unfortunately, there are some users that want to review as much in as little time, choosing the easiest option: Vote, Looks good or Approve.  I have seen users reviewing more than 5 posts within 20 seconds.

Editing posts is often needed but this takes more time and the editor often sees several other quick reviews when finishing the edit (Firsts posts and Late answers) so the I'm done button is no longer available.

This is annoying, but it also works counterproductively. The incentive to perform the needed edits is decreased while this kind of behaviour should be encouraged.

So, I would like to suggest the following improvement to the review system:

- If a person edits a post, during review, and the edit is substantial, then it counts as a review.

And I think we need a way to stop the trigger happy reviewers, possibly using a timed delay.

Comment: @AzizShaikh,  this has nothing to do with Reputation but with "reviewing points".  You have a valid case, but it is another discussion.

Comment: +1. I always try to edit `First Post` or `Late Answer` instead of only voting if required. Mostly in `First Post`, I need to do too many changes. If I don't complete editing within 10-15 seconds, I find **NEXT** button only as it is already voted and reviewed by someone else.

Comment: Agreed, some of those queues are being cleaned out quite quickly which can be indicative of trigger happy reviewers, personally I've seen a number of substandard reviews and/or edits get through. I'm all for some scripting on the back end to see if this is happening.

Comment: @BenLee I am biased as the OP of that other question, but I do think that the [answer by Geoff Dalgas ♦](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149998/135907) there directly answers this question here as well: "We will make a change where edits will always be counted even if another review type has occurred."

Comment: Related: [The current review system encourages faux reviews: some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-faux-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything#comment430842_149621) and [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted)