# Inform me when a Review item outcome was different than I suggested

Tags: feature-request, review

I would like to know when a Review Item (Suggested Edit, Close Vote, etc...) that I voted on ended up being different than how I voted.

I ask this selfishly for two reasons:

- I want to learn from my mistakes.
- I want other people to learn from their mistakes.

Example:

This morning there was a suggested edit that:

- Removed proper capitalization
- Removed proper pluralization
- Edited the SQL to be from spaced over several lines with SELECT/FROM/WHERE/etc... lining up nicely to all on one line
- AND, add a "hmm" (seriously an 'h', with two 'm') into the question.

Two people thought that this was a *good edit*!!

And in all honesty, I'm certain that I've approved edits that other people find equally outrageous.

Please help me (and others) have the opportunity to be better reviewers.

Comment: Good idea. That could be a new link on the review page itself (notifications for that would be too much). Also, could you provide a link to the example question? Did you rollback the edit already?

Comment: I hadn't linked the Review as I was hoping not to throw the either editor, nor the two people who approved it under the bus. If people feel it's necessary I can. Thankfully, two other people Rejected it and I didn't need to rollback. However I did need to on a separate edit today.

Comment: This is a good idea, even if it color-coded it in the `History` or something like that as not to be obtrusive.

Comment: Okay, I respect that. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything This is an ongoing major problem.

Comment: Oh please don't let that end up being a standard notification for all users. I'm annoyed enough with crappy edits getting accepted no matter how I vote. I don't want that shoved in my face each and every time.

Comment: hmm.  Per @Chichiray, can that be a user preference?

Comment: If we could trust all our users to act like mature, responsible people, this would be great. In the real world, I think it would lead to flame-filled comment threads and edit/rollback wars.

Comment: @PopularDemand I expect that many of these issues are because some people just click approve a bit too quickly and either don't care about reading it carefully, or misread a portion of the paragraph. I wouldn't expect edit/rollback wars in the case of quick clickers, nor in the case of people who misunderstood a paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what @bfavaretto suggested in the comments, I would like to see a similar checkbox on the bottom of each suggested edit so that I can choose to be notified for the ones I select.

This would be quite helpful where I reject an edit but deep down I know that the Accept Every Edit Monkeys™ will just blindly hit that Accept button and the edit will need to be rolled back or tidied up in the near future.