# What should I do about bad edits getting accepted?

Tags: discussion, review, review-abuse

I'm aware of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted), which is asking about long term global solutions to the problem, but pending that, what am I supposed to do with things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1510442) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1510518)?

Rolling back the edit will only 'punish' the editor, my concern is that these approvers will just carry on regardless.

So what is current 'policy'?

Flag? Rollback? Scream?

*(The irony is that I am a fervent defender of minor edits - but only when there's nothing glaringly wrong left behind)*

Comment: The second edit looks valid, only some indentation. The first I can't say, not familiar in that area so can't say how relevant is that tag. None look like glaring bad edits.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, weird, the first suggested edit seems to be displaying with [my subsequent correction](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11046855/revisions). The second one I'm not complaining about what they did, but the crap they left behind.

Comment: You edited it after it was already approved, there was recent change where such thing still count as review, however it's a separate revision.

Answer (score 15):

To go through your suggestions:

- Flagging is pointless; it's not like a moderator can do anything about this apart from admonishing the approvers. They are unlikely to want to have to do this hundreds of times a day.
- Rolling back the edit seems a little pointless as well. It's not like the edits actively hurt the post. They just didn't finish the job.
- Screaming will of course help, do that as much as you want.

I think you should follow this 8 step plan:

1. Scream.
2. The posts obviously need more editing. Finish off the job and ensure everything is fixed.
3. Comment to the original editor (they can receive @replies on the post they edited) explaining why their edit was bad and showing them yours as an example.
4. Scream again.
5. If you believe that the approvers did a really bad job (your examples aren't the most egregious examples) then you can track down a post of the approvers and comment, linking to the approval and your edit, explaining exactly why they shouldn't have approved it.

   I would not do this unless you're certain you can be polite and informative. There's no point starting a fight and as the more experienced user and the one who initialized contact you'll be in the wrong.
6. Scream again.
7. Remember that suggested edit queue audits are in place and people are being banned because of it.
8. Smile.

Repeat if necessary.

Comment: +1 for repeated screaming :)

Comment: You forgot oscillation!

Comment: Should not the first point be _Scream again_ too? Supposing the user already done that 8-point plan, he would screaming again from the first point. `;)`

Comment: If in trouble or in doubt, run in circles, scream and shout! - +1 for the @editor in comments. Didn't know that this is possible!