# Stopping bad edits as a user with low rep

Tags: discussion

I understand that i am bringing up a topic that has been discussed relentlessly and that there is a system already in place for preventing bad edits to questions coming through.

I however have had a question title edited recently because the person who edited the title thought he knew better than me what my problem was. He edited the title and now it does not pertain to my issue at all.

Since he edited the title other people have come and edited the body of the post as well to try and make it fit closer to what the title is now, further detracting from my ability to get anyone to help answer the question in the first place.

After some people took interest in the question and attempted to help me solve it they were trying to solve the problem related to the title question and one of them actually gave me negative rep me for having a tag in the question and nothing about that tag in the question. (The part of the question relevant to that tag being edited out by someone previously).

What should i do in the instance that i am having terrible editing on my questions? I have in the past left the bad edits in place since they were put there by someone who is supposedly more important (measuring by rep) than i am on the website.

This question being posted somewhat as a user experience take on the question below.
[What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted)

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual question? The [only question I see](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23959596/revisions) doesn't have any bad edits in my opinion.

Comment: That is the question. It appears as though the bit about jsfiddle never made it into the answer (i thought it was edited out) so i will concede to that. However the title was edited poorly, although i understand they were seeking concision with a initially "seemingly" vague title.

Comment: If you don't want people to edit your titles, then you shouldn't create titles such as "weird issue with css".  Also, EVERY css issue is weird.  Try to be more specific when creating a title.  Revisit the title after you have finished adding your answer.  Often times the process of writing helps you narrow down your issue to something clear and specific that fits nicely in a title.

Comment: I would have to agree with you that the title is vague and should be revised, i didn't know what a good title for my topic was and left it very vague. However when the title was revised incorrectly to something more specific it is much more inaccurate now.